# How can I get this terminal 'at' command to work properly?

Tags: linux, shell, heredoc

Using at to schedule a systems message. I need to run it in a script, so the first option which requires ctrl+d is not viable. ***Also note, in the first option, the pipe fails UNLESS I add a nonsense echo statement below it.***

first option, works but cannot use:

```
    $ at now
    > cat file.txt | write user pts/0
    > echo "nonsense"
    >[ctrl+d]
```

second option, which needs to work:

```
    $ at now << 'END_AT'
    > cat file.txt | write user pts/0
    > END_AT
```

Please note that with or without the nonsense echo in the second option, it fails to cat the contents of the text file. I need this second option to properly display, what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to see if it's getting an error. `cat file.txt 2>&1 | write user pts/0`

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname of the file. Also, it's a UUOC, so use `write user pts/0 < /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: As far as the UUOC: how do you know? Maybe he started out with `cat file.txt` to see its contents. All those clamouring UUOC would have him at that point discard his previous command and do a clumsy edit or do a total rewrite of the command-line. Just to keep or get some UUOC OCD habit going.

Comment: Appreciate the comments guys. So far, both of Barmar's comments have solved the issue. Both including the 2>&1 AND using the syntax of the second comment have resulted in the contents of the file being displayed in the write. Much appreciated. If you don't mind, could you explain the syntax of the first comment, as in, why it would suddenly cause the file contents to be displayed?

Comment: @Roadowl It's not a total rewrite, and in my experience the people who are using UUOC in their examples *don't* know that there's an alternative, and are using it where it becomes an actual problem (such as `cat foo | while ...` and wondering why a variable set/changed inside the loop is unset/unchanged after the loop).